# Understanding cocos2d-x node positioning

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am a bit confused about how to position a `CCNode`. For example, I would like to position the node at the top right of the screen, but down a bit from the top. How would I do this?

I was thinking:

```
getCoins->setAnchorPoint(ccp(0,0));
getCoins->setPosition( ccp(0,1) );
```

But that didn't work.

Could someone explain how to do positioning like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cocos2d-x, the origin (x=0, y=0) is in the bottom-left corner of screen, so X axis starts from the left side and increases to right and Y axis starts from bottom of screen and moves upward.

The anchor point is used for both positioning and rotating an object. An anchor point ranges from between `0, 0` to `1, 1`. An anchor point of `0.5, 0.5` is the center of object.

So for example if you are placing a object with anchor point `0.5, 0.5` to `100, 100` on screen the center of object will be placed on `100, 100`.

For more details about coordinate system and anchor points check [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Coordinate_System)